# How to use contain() function in selenium using java

Tags: selenium

Here is the HTML screenshot with multiple [div] tags.

Parent [div] tag is "default_products_page_container"

child [div] tag is "default_product_display product_view_40" accessories group and few other with different product view number

Question: How can I get only child [div] that has the name starting with "default_product_display" under the parent [div]

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you provide some of your own code?

Comment: String expectedText = "default_product_display product_view";
List<WebElement> allProducts = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='default_products_page_container' and @class=contains("+expectedText+"]"));

Answer (score 0):

This css selector will give you the child that has a name starting with default_product_display:

`By.cssSelector("div div[name^='default_product_display']")`

the `^=` part indicates that the name attribute should start with `default_product_display`